# Python global variable can't be accessed inside function

Tags: python, global-variables, local-variables, pysimplegui, setvalue

I have encountered a problem I don't seem to understand.

```
video_path = "C:/Users/schwitzky/Downloads/Saul-goodman-3d nice res.mp4"

def open_customize_window():

    customize_layout = [[sg.Text('Search for a custom alarm video: '), sg.Button('Search', key='CUSTOM_VIDEO_BUTTON')],
                        [sg.Text('Custom Video Alarm: '), sg.Text(video_path, key='CUSTOM_VIDEO_PATH')]]
    
    customize_window = sg.Window('Customize Alarm', customize_layout, modal=True)

    while True:
        event, values = customize_window.read()
        if event == 'CUSTOM_VIDEO_BUTTON':
            video_path = filedialog.askopenfile()
            video_path = video_path.name
            customize_window['CUSTOM_VIDEO_PATH'].update(video_path)
```

As you can see in the above code, I have a global var `video_path` defined outside the function. In my function, which opens a new window, the user can select a new .mp4 file to choose for his custom alarm. When that happens, I want to set the value of `video_path` to that of the selected file.

But whenever I try to do that, Python doesn't seem to recognize my global var and instead thinks that the `video_path` I reference inside `sg.Text(video_path, key='CUSTOM_VIDEO_PATH')` is a new local variable.

How can I access the value of my global var inside the text element and set the value of my global var to the one chosen from the file dialog?

Comment: Put `global video_path` at the beginning of the function.

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use global variables.

Comment: @quamrana Do you have any suggestions what I should do instead of working with global variables?

Comment: Yes, you can return the value from the function.